# am having issues with the facebook open graph protocol

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to generate the open graph meta tags via js. but when I try testing if its working am getting no output/feedback.

```
function generateOpenGraphMetaTags(title,description,imageUrl) {
    // Create meta tags
    let metaTags = [
        { property: 'og:title', content: title },
        { property: 'og:description', content: description },
        { property: 'og:image', content: imageUrl }
        // Add more Open Graph meta tags as needed
    ];

    // Add meta tags to the document's head
    let head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    metaTags.forEach(function(meta) {
        let tag = document.createElement('meta');
        tag.setAttribute('property', meta.property);
        tag.setAttribute('content', meta.content);
        head.appendChild(tag);
    });
}

// Call the function when the document loads
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', generateOpenGraphMetaTags);
```

I thought when I paste a link to this page into facebook, facebook would crawl the page and retrieve the details and display them on the link.

Comment: Facebook (and other sites that use the OG information, such as email and messaging apps) don't process JavaScript (there is no load event and the code in script tags isn't run). Applications looking for OG information request your html file (and often, just the first 10,000 characters) and searches for the OG meta tags. If the tags aren't found, the application may select other data, such as using your logo image for the site image.

Comment: But the problem is the meta data is generated dynamically. It is actually meant for the content like posts

Comment: Sites that use your OG meta data to communicate what your site is about treat your data as static. Facebook (and others) cache your site information in case someone else shares your URL, rather than rescraping your site. Facebook does have a [share debugger and an API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/getting-started/change-link/) you can use to trigger rescraping,  but you would need to update your OG tags at your server so you could serve an updated html page with the new data.